# Discussing the discrepancy between crude data calculations and hierarchical modelling

Tags: interpretation, reporting

My data has a nested structure, thus temporal trends were calculated using hierarchical modelling.

```
sex ~ year + (1 | town)
```

Males proportion increased by 5% [95% CI: 2; 7], reaching **60%** [95% CI: 50; 70] in the last year of the study.

Calculations on crude data showed that male proportion was **50%** (750/1500) in the last year of the study.

As you see, there is **10%** discrepancy between these analyses.

1. **Do you agree that I should publish the both results?** Modelling gives significance and crude calculations shows the "actual" situation.
2. **Should I address the discrepancy between the analyses or this is self-evident?** How would you address the discrepancy?
3. **And is it correct to say calculations on crude data or are there better terminology or wording?** Raw data, initial data, original data, unadjusted analysis?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's a good idea to publish both results. This is because you should do you uttermost best to explain the situation to the reader. I think that a significant result is not the full story.

To that point, this model isn't beyond criticism. Here you assume a fixed linear trend for the proportion of males (presumably with a logistic link).

*Fixed*, the alternative would be `sex ~ (1 + year | town)`
*Linear*, a bigger problem than the former I think, but harder to solve. Depending on the number of years you are fitting, it may be overly strict to assume a linear trend in time. This doesn't fit "hockeysticks", "bumps" and other things that are very likely a priori in this data. I say "a priori" because I don't know about your data and the number of years. If you are modelling survival over a single year, this is fine.